# invoke a method which is returning an object of generic list class type throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, reflection, invoke

```
public class SpinnerItemAdapter<T extends BaseSpinnerItem> 
                                  extends BaseAdapter 
                                  implements ISpinnerItemAdapter<T> {

    private List<T> _baseSpinnerItemList;

    public List<T> getSpinnerItems() {
        return _baseSpinnerItemList;
    }
}

SpinnerItemAdapter.class.getMethod("getSpinnerItems", new Class[] {}) // ok 
 .invoke(new SpinnerItemAdapter<BaseSpinnerItem>(),null) // throws bellow exception
```

**Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' exception.**

why fails ?

**edit in reply:**

** *isn't the invoke suppose to be... (INSTANCE OF THAT CLASS, ANY PAREMETERS) – 3kings*

```
 /**
 * @param receiver
 *            the object on which to call this method (or null for static methods)
 * @param args
 *            the arguments to the method
 * @return the result
 *
 * @throws NullPointerException
 *             if {@code receiver == null} for a non-static method
 * @throws IllegalAccessException
 *             if this method is not accessible (see {@link AccessibleObject})
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *             if the number of arguments doesn't match the number of parameters, the receiver
 *             is incompatible with the declaring class, or an argument could not be unboxed
 *             or converted by a widening conversion to the corresponding parameter type
 * @throws InvocationTargetException
 *             if an exception was thrown by the invoked method
 */
public native Object invoke(Object receiver, Object... args)
        throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException;
```

** *YOu're passing one argument (null) while getSpinnerItems() doesn't receive any. Try .invoke(new SpinnerItemAdapter()) – Johannes H.*

```
 /** 
 * <p>If the method is static, the receiver argument is ignored (and may be null).
 *
 * <p>If the method takes no arguments, you can pass {@code (Object[]) null} instead of
 * allocating an empty array.
 *
 * <p>If you're calling a varargs method, you need to pass an {@code Object[]} for the
 * varargs parameter: that conversion is usually done in {@code javac}, not the VM, and
 * the reflection machinery does not do this for you. (It couldn't, because it would be
 * ambiguous.)
 *
 */
```

Comment: YOu're passing one argument (`null`) while `getSpinnerItems()` doesn't receive any. Try `.invoke(new SpinnerItemAdapter<BaseSpinnerItem>())`

Comment: @JohannesH. - edit - no

Comment: Did you actually try? Passing nothing to varargs will allocate an empty array, so it works.

But yes, `(Object[]) null` might be even better. however you're only passing `null`, which will be converted to `(Object) null`. You're missing the typecast to an `Object[]`

Comment: i've tried every case befor i get here  - the null was not the problem here  & i've track down problem - i was passing proxy of proxy instead of proxy from original interface - this was causing some sort of loop on proxied object

Answer (score 1):

The documentation ov `invoke` that you copied states:

> @throws `IllegalArgumentException` **if the number of arguments doesn't match the number of parameters**, the receiver is incompatible with the declaring class, or an argument could not be unboxed or converted by a widening conversion to the corresponding parameter type

(highlights mine)

This is exactly where the proble is in your case: you are passing one argument (`null`) to the `getSpinnerItems()` method in the `invoke()` call, but `getSpinnerItems()` doesn't take any.

```
SpinnerItemAdapter.class.getMethod("getSpinnerItems", new Class[] {})
    .invoke(new SpinnerItemAdapter<BaseSpinnerItem>())
```

Varargs arguments can be empty (this will allocate an empty array for the varargs parameters), so this call passes **no** arguments to `getSpinnerItems()`, which is what you want.

---

Edit: in your edit of the question, you point out this piece from the documentation:

> If the method takes no arguments, you can pass `(Object[]) null` instead of allocating an empty array.

However, This is not what you're doing in your call. You are passing `null`, which will be converted to `(Object) null` according to autoboxing conventions. This equals **one** argument for the varargs, so **one** argument that is passed to `getSpinnerItems()`.

If you want to follow recommendation of the doc, it would be:

```
SpinnerItemAdapter.class.getMethod("getSpinnerItems", new Class[] {})
    .invoke(new SpinnerItemAdapter<BaseSpinnerItem>(), (Object[]) null)
```